# Online Exam Test splits when test taken by multiple users simultaniously

Tags: c#, asp.net

My online exam application test in asp.net gets split when multiple users take the test. my 20 question test gets split into 10 10 question to each user who is taking the test simultaniously. I am using session in my appliaction here is the code please help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using BAL;

namespace OnlineExamDesign
{
    public partial class Exam : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static int index = 0;
        static int selection = 0;
        static int QuestionNums = 0;
        clsExam examObj = new clsExam();
        DataSet ds; DataTable dt;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                index = 0;
                selection = 0;
                string set = Session["CandidateSet"].ToString();
                ds = examObj.getQuestion(set);
                Session["Ques"] = ds;
                displayQuestion(index);
                btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
                if (Session["candidateName"] != null)
                    lblCandidateName.Text = Session["candidateName"].ToString();
                clearResultData();
            }


        }

        private void clearRadioButtons()
        {
            rbtnOption1.Checked = false;
            rbtnOption2.Checked = false;
            rbtnOption3.Checked = false;
            rbtnOption4.Checked = false;
        }

        private void clearResultData()
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < clsExam.AnsList.Length; n++)
            {
                clsExam.AnsList[n] = 0;
            }

        }

        private void saveCandidateData()
        {
            Candidate obj = new Candidate();
            obj.Fname = Session["CandidateFName"].ToString();
            obj.Lname = Session["CandidateLName"].ToString();
            obj.Contact = Session["CandidateContact"].ToString();
            obj.Domain = Session["CandidateDomain"].ToString();
            obj.Team = Session["CandidateTeam"].ToString();
            obj.Set = Session["CandidateSet"].ToString();
            obj.ExamStartTime = (DateTime)Session["strttime"];
            obj.ExamEndTime = System.DateTime.Now;
            obj.Score = examObj.score;
            obj.actionCandidateDetails("save");
            Session["Score"] = obj.Score;

        }

        private int displayQuestion(int index)
        {
            ds = (DataSet)Session["Ques"];
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            int num = dt.Rows.Count;

            if (index <= num)
            {
                lblQuestionNum.Text = Convert.ToString((index+1));

                lblQuestion.Text = dt.Rows[index]["questions_question_nvc"].ToString();
                rbtnOption1.Text = dt.Rows[index]["questions_option1_nvc"].ToString();
                rbtnOption2.Text = dt.Rows[index]["questions_option2_nvc"].ToString();
                rbtnOption3.Text = dt.Rows[index]["questions_option3_nvc"].ToString();
                rbtnOption4.Text = dt.Rows[index]["questions_option4_nvc"].ToString();
            }
            else if (index > num - 1)
                btnNext.Enabled = false;
            else if (index <= 0)
                btnPrevious.Enabled = false;

            return num;
        }

        private void retainChoice()
        {
            if ((clsExam.AnsList[index]).Equals(1))
            {
                rbtnOption1.Checked = true;
            }
            else if ((clsExam.AnsList[index]).Equals(2))
            {
                rbtnOption2.Checked = true;
            }
            else if ((clsExam.AnsList[index]).Equals(3))
            {
                rbtnOption3.Checked = true;
            }
            else if ((clsExam.AnsList[index]).Equals(4))
            {
                rbtnOption4.Checked = true;
            }
        }

        protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            btnPrevious.Enabled = true;
            rbtnOptionCheckedChanged(sender, e);
            examObj.storeAns(index, selection);
            selection = 0;
            clearRadioButtons();
            index++;
            int QuestionNums = displayQuestion(index);
            retainChoice();
            if (index >= QuestionNums - 1)
                btnNext.Enabled = false;
        }

        protected void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (index > 0)
            {
                rbtnOptionCheckedChanged(sender, e);
                examObj.storeAns(index, selection);
                selection = 0;
                clearRadioButtons();
                index--;
                displayQuestion(index);
                retainChoice();
                btnNext.Enabled = true;
            }
            else if (index <= 0)
            {
                btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (index < QuestionNums - 1)
            {
                btnNext.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                btnPrevious.Enabled = false;
                btnNext.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        protected void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            examObj.storeAns(index, selection);

            ds = (DataSet)Session["Ques"];
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (dr["questions_answer_nvc"].Equals(clsExam.AnsList[i]))
                {

                    examObj.countScore();
                    i++;
                }
            }
            Response.Write(examObj.score);
            saveCandidateData();
            index = 0;
            clearResultData();
            Response.Redirect("ThankYou.aspx");

        }

        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int i = 0;
            examObj.storeAns(index, selection);

            ds = (DataSet)Session["Ques"];
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (dr["questions_answer_nvc"].Equals(clsExam.AnsList[i]))
                {

                    examObj.countScore();
                    i++;
                }
            }
            Response.Write(examObj.score);
            saveCandidateData();
            index = 0;
            clearResultData();
            Response.Redirect("ThankYou.aspx");

        }

        protected void rbtnOptionCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rbtnOption1.Checked)
                selection = 1;
            else if (rbtnOption2.Checked)
                selection = 2;
            else if (rbtnOption3.Checked)
                selection = 3;
            else if (rbtnOption4.Checked)
                selection = 4;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am going to repeat the sentence I am famous for in our company: ***Static is evil!***

And yes, it is. `static` in a web application means it is shared across all users, meaning that the `index` of user 1 is the same as the `index` for user 2.

You can fix this quite easily by storing your static variables in the session object. I would simply hide that in a property:

```
public int Index
{
    get
    {
        return (Session["Exam_Index"] as int?) ?? 0;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["Exam_Index"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: return (Session["Exam_Index"] as int?) ?? 0; Sir can you please explain this

Comment: Get the value from the session object and try to convert that to an integer. If it fails, default it to 0.